# Validate input for the following condition

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, conditional-statements, floating-point-precision

I came across a question which takes `float` as input and check if the input lies between 10 and 100 otherwise take input again. The rest of question followed this value of k which was easy to solve. But the real problem I got was the validation.

```
   scanf("%f",&k);   
   if(k>10.0 && k<100.0)
   scanf("%f",&k);
   else
   {
   ......//my code
   }
```

But when I submitted, it gave wrong answer the real problem was at the

```
      #Input-10.@
      #Input-@
```

Because for this input, rather than going to else part, it went to if part though the input like

```
       #Input-10
```

was satisfied.

Can anyone give me solution to this problem where the input of float and integer type within this range are only satisfied otherwise not.

Answer (score 2):

You have your comparison operators mixed up (it seems you're retrying only when you get valid input, rather than invalid input).  Also, you only try again once, but I suspect you want to keep retrying until you get valid input.  This is how you can do that:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  double k;
  do{
    cin>>k;
  }while(k<=10||k>=100);

  //the rest of your code goes here
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is invalid C++, and this won't compile since you haven't defined `k`.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking your conditions the other way round. Invert the signs and you will be good. Like:

```
if(k<=10.0 || k>=100.0) //if(k<10.0 || k>100.0) If you want to include 10 and 100
    printf("invalid input range");
```

Or to simplify your program

```
do
{
    scanf("%f",&k);
}while(k<=10.0 || k>=100.0);
```

Comment: The C standard mandates that all floats are representable as doubles, even if the floating-point system is not IEEE 754. So `k<10.0f && k>100.0f` and `k<10.0 && k>100.0` are equivalent as soon as 10 and 100 are representable exactly as floats. This is virtually for any C compiler that provides float at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `;` was a typo. and thanks for your input. corrected it.

Comment: The negation of a && b is (!a) || (!b), please use || or your conditions will always be false.

Comment: can u tell me how this works do u want me to put my earlier else query in this if or to put my if part in this. if i put if part in this then it wont work as i need between 10 &100

Answer (score 0):

Edited, as Paul pointed 10.0 might not be a correct example to explain this.

you can not not use == < or > operators safely when using float. The reason is that the number when entered as 1.1, would not be 1.10000000000000000 when using non integer types. So, define a certain error threshold delta, which can be the finest resolution between two nearest floats.
So, if your 10 is a computed value rather than hardcoded,
float ten=getXX(someinput); suppose getXX() returns some result based on some computations
float hundred=getXX(someinput);

then do comparison like K > (ten-delta) && K < (hundred+delta)

This should be enough i believe.

So, never carry out relation operation on floats/doubles without small error correction factor!

Here is a snippet to demonstrate it http://ideone.com/dxS9OI

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    float eleven=11.0;
    float one_dot_1=1.1;
    float elevenUsingSummation = 0;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        elevenUsingSummation+=one_dot_1;
    }
    printf("------------------------------\n"
        "Floating point testing example \n"
    "one_dot_1(2.10)=%2.10f, one_dot_1(2.20)=%2.20f\n"
    "eleven(2.10)=%2.10f, eleven(2.20)=%2.20f\n"
    "elevenusingsubmission(2.10)=%2.10f, elevenusingsubmission(2.20)=%2.20f\n"
    "(elevenUsingSummation==eleven) evaluates to %s\n",
    one_dot_1, one_dot_1, eleven, eleven, elevenUsingSummation, elevenUsingSummation,
    elevenUsingSummation==eleven?"True":"False"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An article for same is
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/25-floating-point-numbers/

Comment: Some of what you say will be true much of the time, but there are plenty of numbers which can be represented precisely as floating points, 10 being one of them.

Comment: well it is makes the code more reliable i would say. comparison using == in case of float and likes may be dangerous!

Comment: I wouldn't say code becomes "more reliable" as a result of deliberately introducing unnecessary inaccuracies. It's better to deal with the actual problems when you need to rather than just being frightened of floating point and doing things like this left, right and center.

Comment: Paul, I hope you are happy now :)